# How to draw timeseries chart by month,year with d3js

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I'm looking for a way to visualize  data  with `d3.js`. 
Currently i have bar charts for each week but i want to be able to have an options that can allow me to visualise bar charts monthly or yearly.

Is there any option to draw Bar Chart with weekly, monthly values ?

Answer (score 0):

Without having any other context around what your data looks like etc., this should serve as a good starting point:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955